# Increase letter spacing in plain TeX

Tags: spacing, plain-tex, letterspacing

I want to typeset the titles of the sections of my document in capitals, so I need to increase the spacing between the letters.

I am currently using the following (ugly) trick

```
\begingroup
\catcode`/=13 \def/{\kern0.167em}
\catcode` =\active \def {\kern0.5em}
c/h/a/p/t/e/r t/i/t/l/e
\endgroup
```

Is there a better way?
(I would prefer a plain TeX solution but one using pdfTeX/XeTeX extensions is also fine to me.)

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/stop-stealing-sheep/9780133441147/part07.html :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In fact it's not lowercase, above in the file I chose a small caps font ;)

Comment: the `letterspace` package (from `microtype`) works with plain luatex or pdftex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eplain` and `letterspace`, with `pdftex` or `luatex`. For XeTeX you need to set letterspacing in the definition of the chapter font.

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifxetex\else
  \usepackage[letterspace=200]{letterspace}
\fi
\endpackages

\ifxetex
  \font\chapterfont="[lmromancaps10-regular.otf]:letterspace=40" at 16pt
  \def\lsstyle{}
\else
  \font\chapterfont=cmcsc10 at 16pt
\fi

\def\chapter#1{%
  \par\supereject
  \vglue 48pt
  \begingroup
  \baselineskip=24pt
  \chapterfont\lsstyle
  #1
  \par
  \endgroup
  \vskip 24pt
}

\chapter{This is spaced}

This is standard text for the chapter.

\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

xetex version

[image]

```
\font\rm="[lmroman10-regular.otf]"
\font\rmx="[lmroman10-regular.otf]:letterspace=7"

\rm
ABCDEF

\rmx
ABCDEF

\bye
```

If you  add `\input{luaotfload.sty}` as the first line, then you get a version for `luatex`

Comment: Nice! Thank you

Comment: see @wipet's answer for pdftex

Answer (score 7):

pdftex version:

```
\letterspacefont\f=\tenrm 70

ABCDEF

\f ABCDEF 

\bye
```

Note, that the parameter of the `\letterspacefont` pdfTeX primitive is given in 1/1000 em, whilst the font-feature `letterspace` used in LuaTeX and XeTeX has its parameter in 1/100 em.